# Program defensively against ODAC instantclient

Tags: oracle, odt.net

I'm trying to isolate the oracle-client to the application by xcopying the instantclient and setting environment-variables for ORACLE_HOME and PATH in global.asax.cs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923283/what-is-the-minimal-setup-required-to-deploy-a-net-application-with-oracle-clien) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491876/why-doesnt-odp-net-11-xcopy-deployment-work-on-a-machine-with-oracle-db-10-insta), but still get `[OracleException (0x80004005): The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client]` when running on the server. Is there some way to programmatically check client and provider to give a more descriptive error-message?

**EDIT** [This post](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/09/odpnet-provider-is-not-compatible-with.html) has a start. It lists three causes for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the managed oracle-client](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/odp.net.managed) which is available now, then this question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I did a blog post on this very thing.  I used it in our DAL to prevent connections to non supported versions of Oracle.

https://tsells.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/oracle-11g-release-2-and-net-framework-4-0-and-version-checking/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not using `DbProviderFactories`. I'm trying to xcopy-deploy the neccessary files, reference `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` and instanciate `OracleConnection` directly.

Comment: I don't think that is going to work.  You have to register the providers for them to be available for the OS to use.

Comment: Hm, maybe that is the problem then. However the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15167_01/InstallODP.htm) says 'Oracle.DataAccess.dll searches for dependent unmanaged DLLs' in the executable folder first. Aren't those files the provider?