# ORA-01008 with all variables bound

Tags: c#, oracle, oracleclient, ora-01008

I'm using `System.Data.OracleClient` which does parameter-binding by name and are verifying that CommandText and Parameters are in sync:

```
    public string CommandText { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OracleParameter> Parameters { get; set; }

    private void VerifyThatAllParametersAreBound()
    {
        var variableNames = Regex.Matches(CommandText, ":\\w+")
            .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
        var parameteterNames = Parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterName).ToArray();

        var unboundVariables = variableNames.Except(parameteterNames).ToArray();
        if (unboundVariables.Length > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Variable in CommandText missing parameter: "
                + string.Join(", ", unboundVariables) + ".");
        }

        var unboundParameters = parameteterNames.Except(variableNames).ToArray();
        if (unboundParameters.Length > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Parameter that is not used in CommandText: "
                + string.Join(", ", unboundParameters) + ".");
        }
    }
```

Still one query throws `ORA-01008: not all variables bound`. When manually inserting the parameter-values into the offending CommandText the query runs, so the CommandText and Parameters-values should be ok. I'm using : as prefix both for variables and parameternames and it's working for the other queries.

How can I pinpoint the cause of this exception?

Comment: do you have the code making the queries? Also, have you tried with the oracle (or other vendors) .net clients? I think Microsoft are no longer providing the oracle client.

Comment: I vaguely remember an issue with one of the Oracle clients that the parameters had to be bound in exactly the same order they appeared in the query or it wouldn't work - could that be the problem here?

Comment: @Nick - The command was an update with ~40 parameters so for readability and ip-reasons I dropped them. I tried with ODT.NET from Oracle but had trouble deploying it. (See also comment below.)

Comment: I meant [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html). I will try with it again now that there might be a practical reason to use it. Since the error-code is from Oracle I think all parameters are transferred, but maybe it has something to do with datatypes? I create parameters like this `new OracleParameter(":myParam", obj.MyParam)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mistake was not specifing DBNull.Value for null-values. So

```
new OracleParameter(":Foo", item.Foo)
```

had to preplaced with

```
item.Foo == null 
    ? new OracleParameter(":Foo", DBNull.Value) 
    : new OracleParameter(":Foo", item.Foo)
```

I think it was working earlier with ODT.NET without null-checks, but have not confirmed it. Apparently `System.Data.OracleClient` is dropping parameters with null-value.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass **null** as parameter value, you get "Not all variables bound" If you pass **DBNull.Value** you get runtime error somewhere in the OracleClient. To pass NULL, use **string.Empty**, OracleClient converts it to **NULL** for any database type.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one parameter, you need to set **BindByName** to **true**. For example:

```
OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

cmd.BindByName = true;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("parameter1", parameter1));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("parameter2", parameter2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Microsoft has [deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx) OracleClient as part of ADO.NET about 2 years ago.

You may want to consider using Oracle's data access components (ODAC odp.net).  Easy to build-up (and check counts) of parameters using OracleParameter class.  Setup and install docs found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/install112021-200037.html).   Oh, you can get into their Entity framework (and LINQ) support also (still beta i think?).

Something to seriously consider anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I would rather use what both oracle and microsoft recommends, but had to put my attempts [on hold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581752/program-defensively-against-odac-instantclient). With five-digit error-codes I'm a bit disappointed about the generic messages. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on above answers and comments, I made sure the following to resolve this issue:

- parameters are being bound in the same order they appear in the query
- parameter type is specified
- If same parameter value is required more than once in the SQL, name each parameter differently in the SQL (not sure if this is required)

  OracleParameter[] orclParams = new OracleParameter[]
  {
      new OracleParameter{
          ParameterName = "param1",
          OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
          Value = "abc" },
      new OracleParameter{
          ParameterName = "param2",
          OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
          Value = "abc" },
      new OracleParameter{
          ParameterName = "date1",
          OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date,
          Value = myDate }
  };
  SomeFunction(sqlQuery, orclParams.ToList());